# Splitting bulk text file every n line

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, cygwin

I have a folder that contains multiple text files. I'm trying to split all text files at 10000 line per file while keeping the base file name `i.e. if filename1.txt contains 20000 lines the output will be filename1-1.txt (10000 lines) and filename1-2.txt (10000 lines).`

I tried to use `split -10000 filename1.txt` but this is not keeping the base filename and i have to repeat the command for each text file in the folder. I also tried doing `for f in *.txt; do split -10000 $f.txt; done`. This didn't work too.

Any idea how can i do this? Thanks.

Comment: Could you use `split` and then `rename` to change split's output's file names?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
for f in filename*.txt; do split -d -a1 -l10000 --additional-suffix=.txt "$f" "${f%.txt}-"; done
```

Or, written over multiple lines:

```
for f in filename*.txt
do
    split -d -a1 -l10000 --additional-suffix=.txt "$f" "${f%.txt}-"
done
```

How it works:

- `-d` tells `split` to use numeric suffixes
- `-a1` tells `split` to start with only single digits for the suffix.
- `-l10000` tells `split` to split every 10,000 lines.
- `--additional-suffix=.txt` tells `split` to add `.txt` to the end of the names of the new files.
- `"$f"`  tells `split` the name of the file to split.
- `"${f%.txt}-"` tells `split` the prefix name to use for the split files.

#### Example

Suppose that we start with these files:

```
$ ls
filename1.txt  filename2.txt
```

Then we run our command:

```
$ for f in filename*.txt; do split -d -a1 -l10000 --additional-suffix=.txt "$f" "${f%.txt}-"; done
```

When this is done, we now have the original files and the new split files:

```
$ ls
filename1-0.txt  filename1-1.txt  filename1.txt  filename2-0.txt  filename2-1.txt  filename2.txt
```

#### Using older, less featureful forms of `split`

If your split does not offer `--additional-suffix`, then consider:

```
for f in filename*.txt
do 
    split -d -a1 -l10000 "$f" "${f%.txt}-"
    for g in "${f%.txt}-"*
    do 
        mv "$g" "$g.txt"
    done
done
```

Comment: Hm, neither my `man split` nor `split --help` shows anything about the option `--additional-suffix`.  What version do you use?  (Mine is 8.13)

Comment: I'm on linux where `split` is part of GNU coreutils 8.23.

Comment: Thanks.  On Ubuntu 12.04 this is not yet available.  On 14.04 we have version 8.21 which already has this option.  OP should consider this in case his script needs to be portable.

Comment: @Alfe OK.  I added a version that doesn't need `--additional-suffix`.

Answer (score 3):

No need for shell loops, just one simple awk command does it for all files:

```
awk 'FNR%1000==1{if(FNR==1)c=0; close(out); out=FILENAME; sub(/.txt/,"-"++c".txt)} {print > out}' *
```

Answer (score -1):

```
--suffix-length=3
```

If it is going to make more than 9 files you might need to add something like that.