# Extract file content using grep content based on a line delimiter

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I'm trying to extract just the file information using either grep, awk or any linux command

Have: File

```
Getting Table 'TABLEA'
GET TABLE TABLEA
(value(1)
)
/

Getting Table 'TABLEB'
GET TABLE TABLEB
(value(1) 
,other value(2)
)
/
```

WANT

An output to contain the following

```
Getting Table 'TABLEA'
GET TABLE TABLEA
(value(1)
)
/
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444369/splitting-bulk-text-file-every-n-line

Answer (score 0):

That would work:

```
grep -A 4 "^Getting Table 'TABLEA'"
```

It will get the pattern at the start of the line, print it, and continue printing 4 lines afterwards(`-A 4` option)